# How to assign multiple categories based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, series

Here are the categories each with a list of words ill be checking the rows for match:

```
fashion = ['bag','purse','pen']
general = ['knob','hanger','bottle','printing','tissues','book','tissue','holder','heart']
decor =['holder','decoration','candels','frame','paisley','bunting','decorations','party','candles','design','clock','sign','vintage','hanging','mirror','drawer','home','clusters','placements','willow','stickers','box']
kitchen = ['pantry','jam','cake','glass','bowl','napkins','kitchen','baking','jar','mug','cookie','bowl','placements','molds','coaster','placemats']
holiday = ['rabbit','ornament','christmas','trinket','party']
garden = ['lantern','hammok','garden','tree']
kids = ['children','doll','birdie','asstd','bank','soldiers','spaceboy','childs']
```

Here is my code: (I am checking sentences for keywords and assign the row a category accordingly. I want to allow overlapping, so one row could have more than one category)

```
#check if description row contains words from one of our category lists
df['description'] = np.select(
    [
        (df['description'].str.contains('|'.join(fashion))),
        (df['description'].str.contains('|'.join(general))), 
        (df['description'].str.contains('|'.join(decor))),
        (df['description'].str.contains('|'.join(kitchen))),
        (df['description'].str.contains('|'.join(holiday))),
        (df['description'].str.contains('|'.join(garden))),
        (df['description'].str.contains('|'.join(kids)))
    ],
    ['fashion','general','decor','kitchen','holiday','garden','kids'], 
    'Other'
)
```

```
Current Output:

index         description         category
0         children wine glass     kids
1         candles                 decor 
2         christmas tree          holiday
3         bottle                  general
4         soldiers                kids
5         bag                     fashion


Expected Output:

index         description         category
0         children wine glass     kids, kitchen
1         candles                 decor
2         christmas tree          holiday, garden
3         bottle                  general
4         soldiers                kids
5         bag                     fashion
```

Comment: Please add a sample input and the expected output

Comment: children is not a catetory. kids is and children is part of kids. Can you update expected result please

Comment: Indecency? What? I don't think that word means what you think it means.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, haha. I didn't see that. I updated it to column. Yotam, you may want to check the title.

Comment: You're right I ment *indensies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option using `apply()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'description': ['children wine glass',
'candles',
'christmas tree',
'bottle',
'soldiers',
'bag']})

def categorize(desc):
    lst = []
    for w in desc.split(' '):
        if w in fashion:
            lst.append('fashion')
        if w in general:
            lst.append('general')
        if w in decor:
            lst.append('decor')
        if w in kitchen:
            lst.append('kitchen')
        if w in holiday:
            lst.append('holiday')
        if w in garden:
            lst.append('garden')
        if w in kids:
            lst.append('kids')
    return ', '.join(lst)
            
   df.apply(lambda x: categorize(x.description), axis=1)
```

Outuput:

```
0      kids, kitchen
1              decor
2    holiday, garden
3            general
4               kids
5            fashion
```

Comment: I'm not well versed in numpy, but the docs https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html read that if multiple conditions are found, only the first is used. Perhaps a different numpy option will return multiple answers.

Comment: It turns out the loop would make an instance " party candles holder " be in a decor, decor ,decor category, instead of all being in the decor category

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

Comments above each line provides you details on what I am trying to do.

Steps:

1. Convert all the categories into `key:value` pair. Use values in the
   category as key and the category as value. This is to enable you to
   search for the value and map it back to key
2. Split the description field into multiple columns using
   split(expand)
3. Do a match for key value on each column. The result will be
   categories and NaNs
4. Join all of these back into a column with ', ' separated to get final result while excluding NaNs. Apply pd.unique() on it again to remove duplicate categories

The six lines of code you need are:

```
dict_keys = ['fashion','general','decor','kitchen','holiday','garden','kids']
dict_cats = [fashion,general,decor,kitchen,holiday,garden,kids]
s_dict = {val:dict_keys[i] for i,cats in enumerate(dict_cats) for val in cats}
temp = df['description'].str.split(expand=True)
temp = temp.applymap(s_dict.get)
df['new_category'] = temp.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[x.notnull()]), axis = 1)
df['new_category'] = df['new_category'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(pd.unique(x.split(','))))
```

If you have more categories, just add it to dict_keys and dict_cats. Everything else stays the same.

The full code with comments begins here:

```
import pandas as pd

c = ['description','category']
d = [['children wine glass','kids'],
['candles','decor'], 
['christmas tree','holiday'],
['bottle','general'],
['soldiers','kids'],
['bag','fashion']]
df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns = c)

fashion = ['bag','purse','pen']
general = ['knob','hanger','bottle','printing','tissues','book','tissue','holder','heart']
decor =['holder','decoration','candels','frame','paisley','bunting','decorations','party','candles','design','clock','sign','vintage','hanging','mirror','drawer','home','clusters','placements','willow','stickers','box']
kitchen = ['pantry','jam','cake','glass','bowl','napkins','kitchen','baking','jar','mug','cookie','bowl','placements','molds','coaster','placemats']
holiday = ['rabbit','ornament','christmas','trinket','party']
garden = ['lantern','hammok','garden','tree']
kids = ['children','doll','birdie','asstd','bank','soldiers','spaceboy','childs']

#create a list of all the lists
dict_keys = ['fashion','general','decor','kitchen','holiday','garden','kids']
dict_cats = [fashion,general,decor,kitchen,holiday,garden,kids]

#create a dictionary with words from the list as key and category as value
s_dict = {val:dict_keys[i] for i,cats in enumerate(dict_cats) for val in cats}

#create a temp dataframe with one word for each column using split
temp = df['description'].str.split(expand=True)

#match the words in each column against the dictionary
temp = temp.applymap(s_dict.get)

#Now put them back together and you have the final list
df['new_category'] = temp.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x[x.notnull()]), axis = 1)

#Remove duplicates using pd.unique()
#Note: prev line join modified to ',' from ', '
df['new_category'] = df['new_category'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(pd.unique(x.split(','))))
print (df)
```

The output of this will be: (I kept your `category` column and created new one called `new_category`

```
           description category     new_category
0  children wine glass     kids    kids, kitchen
1              candles    decor            decor
2       christmas tree  holiday  holiday, garden
3               bottle  general          general
4             soldiers     kids             kids
5                  bag  fashion          fashion
```

The output including `'party candles holder'` is :

```
            description category     new_category
0   children wine glass     kids    kids, kitchen
1               candles    decor            decor
2        christmas tree  holiday  holiday, garden
3                bottle  general          general
4  party candles holder     None   holiday, decor
5              soldiers     kids             kids
6                   bag  fashion          fashion
```

Comment: As we assign each word a column to check, It turns out the loop would make an instance " party candles holder " be in a decor, decor ,decor category, instead of all being in the decor category

Comment: Good point. Thats a bug I didn't notice. Will fix shortly.

Comment: Fixed the bug. See updated changes and output.

Comment: Still there are rows with duplicate words :
decor,  general,  decor                5084 
decor,  holiday,  decor                4725 
holiday,  decor                        4549
kitchen,  kitchen                      4164
decor,  kitchen                        3740
kitchen,  kitchen,  decor              2315
kitchen,  general,  decor

Comment: Can i get examples of items that caused this duplicates. I will revisit the code and see if there are other improvements to make